# WPF BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization + ObservableCollection + Reentrancy

Tags: wpf, thread-safety, observablecollection

Firstly I am terrible at titles and articulating my problem at hand.

I am producing a file-system like structure. Files and Folders are stored in a local sqlite db, you have File entities and Folder entities.

When the screen first opens, goes to the local db and fetches the data and pushes it into the ObservableCollection. This is done on a new background thread.

Here's the problem, if you have 50,000 items, it seems like WPF's new BindingOperation mechanism for cross thread collection access, does some special tricks to queue all the changes to the UI on another thread which then trickles it onto the Dispatcher.

Now obviously I have no control over how it does this. But my question is, how do I handle reentrancy in these scenarios? If the user was to spam-click a reload button that I have, how do I either cancel all these queued UI updates that are slow and pending, or how do I know there's still so many pending UI updates?

It seems rather slow on the updates, with 50,000 items it takes at least a minute or 2 to completely process all items into the list.

Comment: Can you show 50000 items in the UI? If not why are you loading all 50000, load them on demand instead and use virtualization. As for the "spam-click" issue, use Commanding and CanExecute to disable the reload button while items are loading.

Comment: 50,000 was arbitrary even at 5000 the the dispatcher was very slow at pacing it out with pumping changes to the UI.   Furthermore, data virtualisation isn’t trivial to do. There’s no built in support and there are scenarios that need to be catered for, multi selection, ctrl click selection. WPF out of the box doesn’t support that. UI virtualisation is enabled already.